# What is the difference between various cuts of steak?

Tags: beef, steak, ingredient-selection

I'm sure each has their own differences in texture (and cost) but don't really know exactly what they are or what they are best used for. I like bone in ribeyes so I haven't bothered to try experimenting with other cuts such as:

- Boneless Ribeye
- T-Bone
- New York Strip
- Sirloin
- Porterhouse
- Delmonico
- Filet
- Filet Mignon
- Rib

I'm mostly looking at this from the perspective of grilling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of sites that provide diagrams and information on the different cuts, one fairly extensive resource is [Beef Glossary - Different Beef Cuts , Diagram, Types Of Meat](http://www.thenibble.com/REVIEWS/MAIN/meats/beef/glossary.asp)

Edit: Made a change due to comment.

Comment: We're looking to have this place be the definitive and not just a dump of links. Quote the site, link to it.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand?

Comment: +1 Good link to an excellent information packed site, Quoting the good stuff from there is neigh on impossible.

Comment: @ran that would be a giant wall of content, and it includes diagrams, to boot.